# How to get updated Atom feeds programmatically in java?

Tags: java, push, atom-feed

I am able to read Atom feeds in a Java program using Adbera, but i need to get updated Atom feeds from a server, similar to subscription of a feed.

I don't want to poll and pull the feeds which is resource consuming. What is the correct way to proceed here?

Comment: Did You searched an articles how it could be done ???

Comment: yes, i was following https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ABDERA/Creating+and+Consuming+Atom+Documents which explains about pulling data.